# Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform

Tags: android, admob, google-ad-manager

I have tried to use Admob in my application and i have tried the following. could you please tell me why i'm getting this error?

**activity.main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"/>
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="/6253334/dfp_example_ad"
                           ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,DB5C6285034D8192153E5D66D726E418"
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package test.admobtest;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
                re.setTesting(true);
                adView.loadAd(re);
            };
        }.start();      

    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.admobtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="test.admobtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**log:**

```
07-08 10:34:34.589: I/webclipboard(26978): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4052f5d0
07-08 10:34:34.849: I/webclipboard(26978): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4052f5d0
07-08 10:34:34.909: E/ActivityThread(26978): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
07-08 10:34:34.929: W/Ads(26978): loadAd called while the ad is already loading, so aborting.
07-08 10:34:34.979: I/Ads(26978): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"session_id":"10000751322559007096","seq_num":"2","slotname":"\/6253334\/dfp_example_ad","u_w":320,"msid":"test.admobtest","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.test.admobtest","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"40440","u_audio":3,"kw":[],"u_sd":1,"ms":"n54ldDZ15bdyTg9xXgxtdXMgomxIrXGdOYvqk2l8bUwTFSRmnmpAVljV0IHyknLTNWRCdF8oj52F_2JERnz-3C-DJsIQ9wGFBnH88tqEb9BjAtNZ3-ni5am3uWBAyUygwgpiyTTzY6cgUeA4g_QnU5Qrh3savu2bMY_3nsjuW9fH7W7x-5HC_oDuaVe6U05Pypm5FMyWGYFqBd0-s6_p_IFm0AhPOYvujrNtCxqC4inyELVT2E0laAKwjvaWVqA5yzjILYNspqByel6t3TMiiZ3z3k7Qc9HYIRsHwRV3cbdtSb_pk5eZCgjTZhaippVWsXwUC-eoMxMdBtfqUHqA9w","mv":"80210006.com.android.vending","isu":"DB5C6285034D8192153E5D66D726E418","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":480,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":20956});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-08 10:34:34.999: W/webcore(26978): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following and working now

**Work With Admob - put jar file and set path:**

1. download AdMob SDK from Google site(could be a different link depends on country) https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download?hl=de
2. unzip the file into a directory (no matter where)
3. create a "libs" folder inside your project in Eclispe. BE SURE THAT THE FOLDER IS NAMED "libs" AND NOT "lib". THIS MISTAKE IS OFTEN DONE
4. copy the jar file from admob folder into Your project into the libs folder
   click right mouse button on jar file inside lib folder and choose Build Path-->add to build path
5. To get sure everything is really done, click right mouse button on Your project and choose properties
6. select Java-Build-Path and go to Libraries Tab
7. select add external jar and select this jar from your admob folder
8. select ok

**Referred from** [Android app fail to start after adding admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550718/android-app-fail-to-start-after-adding-admob?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
adview.loadAd(new AdRequest())
```

in UI thread hope it will help you.

Comment: hi that's i did in my mainactiviy.java

Answer (score 0):

It could also be because the user hasn't logged into Gplus or hasn't bothered installing G+ or Google Play Services?

I'm getting this message in the logs but the ads are running fine.