# Error using admob

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I have followed an admob tutorial to add an admob banner to my application (this one http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Advertisements-to-Your-Android-Applications-Using-Admob)

I add it using the following code

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    ads:adSize="BANNER" 
    ads:adUnitId="a151ebd8dece188" 
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" > 
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

I also have in my manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

</application>
```

and also

However, whenever I open this view on the app it crashes. I have looked at many admob questions on here but cannot find anything obvious missing from my code. Is it something simple that I am missing?

Comment: post your logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the following things:

- Uptade eclipse and android SDK
- Download adMob SDK from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download?hl=de) and add jar in your libs folder. Also don't forget to add jar to your build path
- Also, don't forget to set permissions (internet, access network state)
- If nothing works, follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550718/android-app-fail-to-start-after-adding-admob/15551286#15551286) and it should work!

Let me know if it works

Comment: Is it necessary to have any reference to the admob in my .java file? I notice in the tutorial you link to it is the same as mine (without any reference) but I have seen some where some simple script is needed in the src aswell. Do you use this?

Comment: No, I don't use any reference in java file. Just the part of the code in XML file and it works fine.